# Event to Lose focus of a TextBox - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove focus from a textbox. if i need to set focus for a textbox we have .focus() method. Similarly is there any other method to remove focus from a textbox using javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe http://api.jquery.com/blur/ ?

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/LekisS/7xsfx/1/

Comment: NO. That is an event. That will fire when the focus gets out from an object. my requirement is to remove focus from a textbox

Comment: Can you set this question (and your previous ones) to answered?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the focus somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's the DOM-HTML standard [blur()](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-6750689).